# Susy span columns

Tags: css, sass, susy-compass

I have this markup:

```
  <div class="test-div">
    <p>p 1</p>
    <p>p 2</p>
  </div>
```

and these styles:

```
+with-grid-settings(8)
  div.test-div
    +container
    +susy-grid-background
    margin-bottom: 10px

    p
      height: 40px
      outline: 1px solid red
      +span-columns(5, 8)
```

and it outputs this:
[image]
The widths of the p's are not 5 columns wide. They seem to be 4 and a bit wide and not 5 as I have specified.

Any ideas? This is not real code by the way, it is a test case that I created after experiencing this issue elsewhere so I simplified it and still can;t figure out why this is occurring.

Update: This is happening on Susy 1.0.8, Susy 1.0.3 is fine and works as expected.

Comment: I can't recreate the error with the given code, which means the problem is somewhere else in your code. Can you try to isolate a section of code that shows the error on its own?

Comment: Hmm, I would but I have no way of giving you access as it's local, but with the above code on 1.0.8 I get the issue and on 1.0.3 I don't. It's odd.

Comment: It breaks with *only* the code above? I don't need access to your full project, I just need a section of code that breaks when it is *the only code in the project*. Does that make sense?